# CRM 2011 how to use SharePointDocumentLocation

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm trying to use the following code to retrieve the SharePoint URL of a record:

```
RetrieveAbsoluteAndSiteCollectionUrlRequest retrieveRequest = new RetrieveAbsoluteAndSiteCollectionUrlRequest
        {
            Target = new EntityReference(SharePointDocumentLocation.EntityLogicalName, _spDocLocId)
        };
        RetrieveAbsoluteAndSiteCollectionUrlResponse retrieveResponse = (RetrieveAbsoluteAndSiteCollectionUrlResponse)_service.Execute(retrieveRequest);

        return retrieveResponse.AbsoluteUrl.ToString();
```

But it says that SharePointDocumentLocation does not exist and has asked for a reference to it. I can't find any reference for this and am not sure how to get it working. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SharePointDocumentLocation` records are created:

- Only if SharePoint integration has been configured for that entity, **and**
- only if that the record that will be home to the SharePointDocumentLocation has been visited by a user in the UI (it is at this point that CRM invokes the SharePoint web services and creates the location) - until then, no location record or SharePoint folder will exist.

So this invites the question: How are you getting `_spDocLocId`?

Comment: Its the result of a fetch on the sharepointdocumentlocation table that has the regardingobjectid as the record ID. I've seen other examples of this code with the same references and nearly the same code as mine but i cannot see where this SharePointDocumentLocation is being defined

Answer (score 0):

There are [two options for SharePoint integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327818.aspx): Automatic and Manual.  Manual is what you get when you do not specify a URL in the Document Management Settings dialog.
The AbsoluteURL attribute is used in the Manual approach.  It contains a full path to a specific SP folder.

If you configure SP Document Locations and add a record or two by clicking Documents on an Entity that you enabled (via Doc Mgmt Settings) and specifiying a URL (doesn't have to be real) you will be able to see records in your database in the FilteredSharePointDocumentLocation view:

`select * from FilteredSharePointDocumentLocation`

Comment: When i set it up i specified the base URL of the sharepoint site, so i'm guessing that'll make it automatic then? All i want to do is get the complete sharepoint URL of the current record, but i can't find an example that does it in a way that works for me

Comment: From what I can tell, the "automatic" approach requires you to "walk up the chain" to determine the full path.  For a Contact named "John Doe" who works for an Account named "Account1" the automatic integration builds out a folder structure like this: \Accounts\Account1\Contacts\John Doe\

Comment: I see, so would it be easiest then to go to the database from my plugin to work up the chain and construct the URL?